# Image conversion in python

Tags: python, image

I have a folder which contains 2 folders with images in them. The images are in .obj format and I would like to do a for loop to convert from .obj to .jpg

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Do you know how to convert a single image file from OBJ to JPG programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this git repo [Link](https://github.com/pclausen/obj2png)for your use,  a package created for converting obj files to jpg created by Peter Clausen. For going into the folder and checking each of the files with ".obj" extension.

Check out this discussion if you need more options to going through the required folders [Discussion Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python)

```
import glob, os
os.chdir("/mydir")
for file in glob.glob("*.obj"):
   //convert from obj to jpg
```